# How to assign a variable in ViewDataDictionary based on an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view rendered as:

```html
<div>
    @Html.Partial("/_PartialView.cshtml", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "ControllerName", "Controller1" }, { "Attribute1", Model.Attribute1 }, { "Attribute2", Model.Attribute2 }, { "isSelected", "isTrue" } })
</div>
```

I need to change this value of `isSelected` key and assign it a true or false based on whether a checkbox is selected.

```
$('#checkBox1').click(function () {
    if ($('#checkBox1').is(':checked')) {
        // set isSelected to true here
    } else {
        // set isSelected to false here
    });
```

How can I set the value of`isSelected` and render different partial views accordingly, in `_PartialView.cshtml`? If i can somehow get this value set as true or false, I can simply use an `if` condition to hide or display selected html elements.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

This is how I am accessing the variables in Partial;

```
 @{
        var att1 = (int)ViewData["Attribute1"];
        var att2= (int)ViewData["Attribute2"];
        var controller = (string)ViewData["ControllerName"];
        var isSelected = (bool)ViewData["isSelected"];
    }
```

Part of HTML code:

```
<div>
    <li>
    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload </button>
    </li>
    <li>
    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Download </button>
    </li>
    @if(isSelected)
     {
      @*Display this button*@
      <li>
      <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Delete </button>
      </li>
     }
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is output by the partial?

Comment: You cannot change the `isSelected` variable that executes on the server through JS. All you can do is to mimic the effect it has on the rendering of the Partial on the server within your client side code. To help you with that we need to see the content of the Partial

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how MVC works... The server side objects (like ViewData) are only available while rendering the page, while the click event will be after this... You probably want to use an ajax call to render the partial view after the click... have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This might seem ridiculous, but I could directly access the button in the partial view from them main view itself, as it was being rendered in the same HTML page, and a simple `$(#id).hide()` and `$(#id).show()` helped me achieve my goal.

But, the question still remains, if a variable, that is not in the view model, is to be passed using ViewData, how can it be done?

Moreover, will it be any different for a boolean variable?